# add space to every word's end in a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, concatenation

Here I have a string:

```
*line = "123 567 890  ";
```

with 2 spaces at the end. I wish to add those 2 spaces to 3's end and 7's end to make it like this:

```
"123  567  890"
```

I was trying to achieve the following steps:

1. parse the string into words by words list (array of strings). From upstream function I will get values of variables word_count, *line and remain.
2. concatenate them with a space at the end.
3. add space distributively, with left to right priority.
4. concatenate everything together to make it a new *line.

Word_count is number of words in a *line, remain is the number of spaces remained.

Here is a part of my *faulty* code:

```
int add_space(char *line, int remain, int word_count)
{
    if (remain == 0.0)
        return 0; // Don't need to operate.

    int ret;
    char arr[word_count][line_width];
    memset(arr, 0, word_count * line_width * sizeof(char));

    char *blank = calloc(line_width, sizeof(char));
    if (blank == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "calloc for arr error!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++)
    {
        ret = sscanf(line, "%s", arr[i]); // gdb shows somehow it won't read in.
        if (ret != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occured!\n");
            return -1;
        }
        arr[i] = strcat(arr[i], " "); // won't compile.
    }

    size_t spaces = remain / (word_count * 1.0);
    memset(blank, ' ', spaces + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count - 1; i++)
    {
        arr[0] = strcat(arr[i], blank); // won't compile.
    }

    memset(blank, ' ', spaces);
    arr[word_count-1] = strcat(arr[word_count-1], blank);

    for (int i = 1; i < word_count; i++)
    {
        arr[0] = strcat(arr[0], arr[i]);
    }

    free(blank);
    return 0;
}
```

It is not working, could you help me find the parts that do not work and fix them please? Thank you guys.

Comment: How does it not work.  Please let us know what the ACTUAL problem is.

Comment: A line like `char arr[word_count][line_width];` tells me that you have allocated some fixed space for your 2D array of `char`. But `arr[0]` = strcat(arr[i], blank);` will try to overwrite the pointer you had - leaving all kinds of strange memory issues.

Comment: As an aside, if `remain` is of type `int`, you want to do `if(remain == 0)` not `if(remain == 0.0)`. But that is not your issue...

Comment: If this does compile, you shouldn't run it without fixing all the compiler warnings first. There are many errors.

Comment: Actually you don't want to *add* spaces, you want to have the same number of spaces as as the end of the string, after 3's and 7's, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Edit]*** complete code added to bottom, with corrections to original snippets

Your desire then, as I understand it is to take an existing line of some length, and rewrite it to a new line of the same length as the original, but filling in spaces as evenly distributed as possible, with no space after the last word:  For example:

"This is my original sentence    " (four spaces at end - string length is 32)

|T|h|i|s| |i|s| |m|y| |o|r|i|g|i|n|a|l| |s|e|n|t|e|n|c|e| | | | |

You would like to redistribute the spaces such that the original length, 32, is preserved:

|T|h|i|s| | |i|s| | |m|y| | |o|r|i|g|i|n|a|l| | |s|e|n|t|e|n|c|e|.

The following should provide a set of steps you can implement in your code to distribute your words evenly across a line maintaining its original length.

First, store original line length:

```
int origLen = strlen(line);
```

Parse the string a first time using `strtok()` with space, `" "` as the delimiter, for the purpose of collecting the following:

***1) the number of words***
 ***2) the cumulative length of all the words***:

```
char *buf;
char temp[80];    
char lineKeep[80];
int accumLen=0;
int wordCount=0;
int numSpaces;

strcpy(lineKeep, line);

buf = strtok(lineKeep, " ");
while(buf)
{
    strcpy(temp, buf);
    accumLen += strlen(temp)+1;//+1 because each word includes one following space
    wordCount++;
    buf = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
accumLen--; //remove last space
```

Now you can repeat the parse, but this time you have the information you need to re-construct the string as it is parsed:

```
numSpaces = (origLen - accumLen)+1;//determine number of trailing spaces after last word
                                   //+1 to compensate for space at end of last word.

//parse line, place words and extra spaces  
int spcToAdd;  //number spaces added to every word except last
int extraSpc;  //remainder spaces to distribute  

spcToAdd = numSpaces/(wordCount - 1);
extraSpc = numSpaces%(wordCount - 1);

memset(lineKeep, 0, 80);

buf = strtok(line, " ");
while(buf)
{
    strcat(lineKeep, buf);
    for(i=0;i<spcToAdd;i++) strcat(lineKeep, " ");
    if(extraSpc > 0) strcat(lineKeep, " "), extraSpc--;
    buf = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

That should do it.

***[EDIT]***
*Complete code, with corrections to original snippets:*

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
int main(void)
{
    char line[]="this is my original line      ";
    char *buf;
    char temp[80];    
    char lineKeep[80];
    int accumLen=0;
    int wordCount=0, count;
    int numSpaces;
    int i;
    int origLen = strlen(line);

    strcpy(lineKeep, line);
    printf("Original with \"*\" to demark spaces :*%s*\n", lineKeep);
    buf = strtok(lineKeep, " ");
    while(buf)
    {
        strcpy(temp, buf);
        accumLen += strlen(temp)+1;//+1 because each word includes one following space
        wordCount++;
        buf = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    accumLen--; //remove last space

    //second part
    numSpaces = (origLen - accumLen);//determine number of trailing spaces after last word
                                       //+1 to compensate for space at end of last word.
    //parse line, place words and extra spaces  
    int spcToAdd;  //number spaces added to every word except last
    int extraSpc;  //remainder spaces to distribute  

    spcToAdd = numSpaces/(wordCount - 1); //Add one extra space
    extraSpc = numSpaces%(wordCount - 1); //while they last add additional space

    memset(lineKeep, 0, 80);

    count = 0;
    buf = strtok(line, " ");
    while(buf)
    {
        count++;
        strcat(lineKeep, buf);
        if(count < wordCount)
        {
            strcat(lineKeep, " "); //normally occuring space
            for(i=0;i<spcToAdd;i++) strcat(lineKeep, " ");
            if(extraSpc > 0) strcat(lineKeep, " "), extraSpc--;
        }
        buf = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    lineKeep[strlen(lineKeep)]=0;
    printf("modified with \"*\" to demark spaces :*%s*\n", lineKeep);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

***Image of results from this code:***

[image]

***[EDIT]*** *OP original code with comments, and some edits* (not fully debugged)

```
int add_space(char *line, int remain, int word_count)
{
    int line_width;  //added

    if (remain == 0.0)
        return 0; // Don't need to operate.

    line_width = strlen(line);

    int ret;
    char arr[word_count][line_width]; //line width not originally defined, 
    memset(arr, 0, word_count * line_width * sizeof(char));

    char *blank = calloc(line_width, sizeof(char));
    if (blank == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "calloc for arr error!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++)
    {
        ret = sscanf(line, "%s", arr[i]); // gdb shows somehow it won't read in.
        if (ret != 1)                     // each time this loops around, "this" is placed into arr[i];
        {                                 // "line" is not changing, strtok will traverse line
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occured!\n");
            return -1;
        }
        //arr[i] = strcat(arr[i], " ");      // won't compile.
        strcpy(arr[i],strcat(arr[i], " ")); // assignment of char array to char array uses strcpy, or sprintf, et. al.
        //each loop now adds " " -> "this " 
                                            // Note: you can assign char to char using =, but not char arrays
    }
    size_t spaces = remain / (word_count * 1.0); //size_t == uint, mult by float is set back into uint.
    memset(blank, ' ', spaces + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count - 1; i++)
    {
        //arr[0] = strcat(arr[i], blank);     // won't compile.
        strcpy(arr[i],strcat(arr[i], blank)); // Same as above. and index of arr[] should be i
    }

    memset(blank, ' ', spaces);
    //arr[word_count-1] = strcat(arr[word_count-1], blank); //same
    strcpy(arr[word_count-1],strcat(arr[word_count-1], blank));  //at this point, each arr[i] 
                                                                 //contains "test   \0" (3 spaces and NULL)
    for (int i = 1; i < word_count; i++)
    {
        //arr[0] = strcat(arr[0], arr[i]); //same
        strcpy(arr[0], strcat(arr[0], arr[i])); 
    } //at this point arr[0] contains "test   test   test   test   t"
      //ran out of room, note there is no NULL terminator '\0' at end.
    free(blank);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note - the number of words and the number of extra spaces are given as inputs to the original function. Apart from that, you and I have a very similar approach, although I'm working backwards from the end (so I do the rewrite in-place), and I don't use `strtok` (which would be hard, since I start at the end)...

Comment: Thank you very much. I have altered my code accordingly. The numSpaces  wordCount are known from upstream function (remain, word_count). This should save some work.

Comment: You are welcome.  And yes, I saw they were given parameters after I had already started :)

Comment: @hlx98007 - for what it is worth, I have annotated your original code, and posted it at the end of my answer.  You really were not that far off, look at the comments to see my suggestions (things you probably already know by now)

Comment: I debugged your original code only so far as to get it to build, so I could better offer suggestions as to how you could proceed if you did want to go that route.  I never ran it.  As I pointed out, strtok and strcat are (almost) essential for what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will keep that in mind for future study.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative suggestion - probably faster, and using less memory.

First - notice that the line you return will be the same size as the line you start with - so we just need to move words and add spaces. Your current code seems to make no attempt to actually return the fixed string, as far as I can discern…

Start at the end of the string to count the number of "extra spaces" (I think this is your `remain` value). Now work backwards through the string until you find the beginning of the last word, and move it.

I wrote an example - with some debug statements to make it more obvious what is going on, and including '*' instead of ' ' when a space is added. This shows you more clearly what it's doing (although you will want to replace the '*' with ' ' when you use this code, obviously).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int distributeSpaces(char* s, int wordCount, int spaceCount);

int main(void) {
  char *myString = "There is a house in New Orleans       ";
  char *sCopy;
  sCopy = malloc(strlen(myString)+1);
  strcpy(sCopy, myString);
  printf("Initial string: '%s'\n", myString);
  distributeSpaces(sCopy, 7, 7);
  printf("\nString is now '%s'\n", sCopy);
  return 0;
}

int distributeSpaces(char* s, int wordCount, int spaceCount) {
  int ii, length;
  int wordLength, wordEnd;
  int spaceLeft = spaceCount + 1;
  length = strlen(s);
  printf("string is %d characters long\n", length);
  wordEnd = length - spaceLeft - 1;
  wordLength = 0;
  for(ii = length - spaceLeft - 1; ii > 0; ii--) {
    wordLength++;
    if(s[ii] == ' ') {
      // printf("found space - moving %d characters from %d to %d\n", wordLength, ii, ii+spaceLeft);
      printf("before memmove, string is '%s'\n", s);
      memmove(&s[ii+spaceLeft], &s[ii+1], wordLength);
      printf("after memmove, string is now '%s'\n", s);
      memset(&s[ii], '*', spaceLeft);
      printf("after memset, string is now '%s'\n", s);
      spaceLeft -= spaceLeft / wordCount--;
      // printf("space left is now %d\n", spaceLeft);
      wordLength = 0;
      ii--;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Initial string: 'There is a house in New Orleans       '
string is 38 characters long
before memmove, string is 'There is a house in New Orleans       '
after memmove, string is now 'There is a house in New OrleansOrleans'
after memset, string is now 'There is a house in New********Orleans'
before memmove, string is 'There is a house in New********Orleans'
after memmove, string is now 'There is a house in New***New**Orleans'
after memset, string is now 'There is a house in*******New**Orleans'
before memmove, string is 'There is a house in*******New**Orleans'
after memmove, string is now 'There is a house in***in**New**Orleans'
after memset, string is now 'There is a house******in**New**Orleans'
before memmove, string is 'There is a house******in**New**Orleans'
after memmove, string is now 'There is a houshouse**in**New**Orleans'
after memset, string is now 'There is a*****house**in**New**Orleans'
before memmove, string is 'There is a*****house**in**New**Orleans'
after memmove, string is now 'There is a**a**house**in**New**Orleans'
after memset, string is now 'There is****a**house**in**New**Orleans'
before memmove, string is 'There is****a**house**in**New**Orleans'
after memmove, string is now 'There isis**a**house**in**New**Orleans'
after memset, string is now 'There***is**a**house**in**New**Orleans'

String is now 'There***is**a**house**in**New**Orleans'
```

I think that's what you were after.

Comment: I like the step-by-step progress of the string you display.

Comment: What if your string is "There is a house in New OrleansOrleans  " with 2 spaces at the end. Your code would add both 2 after "There". It was supposed to add 1 space after "there" and 1 space after "is".

Comment: @hlx98007 - did you call `distributeSpaces(sCopy, 7, 2);` when you changed your string? Because I was assuming (as you said in the question) that the number of spaces to be distributed was given as a parameter; when I did that, I did indeed get `There**is**a*house*in*New*OrleansOrleans` as intended. Obviously you could count the number of spaces at the start of the function rather than passing it as a parameter. How did you come up with "Your code would add both 2 after 'There'"? It's not what happens for me...

Comment: I did, the output text gave a loosy left look (too many spaces on the left). I didn't know why either. See the output here: http://pastebin.com/YiSUB2a2

Comment: Thanks for providing a sample. I looked at it - it seems you are passing values for "wordCount" and "spaceCount" that don't correspond to the number of words in the line, or the number of spaces at the end of the string. My code assumes both are correct… Example (from your pastebin sample): `String: "the width of your browser ", spaceCount=5, tf=false, wordCount=16, length=30)`, when in fact length = 26, wordCount = 5, spaceCount = 1 (as given). It would be easy to write code that computes these things - I just assumed they were being passed in correctly… Maybe I just misunderstood.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to reset wordCount to 0 everytime I did a loop. The length is the defined length of the string, so no matter "abc" or "abc def" as long as length = 30, the string is 30 char long, and must have spaces to fill up the string where possible. I have now fixed it.

Comment: One more question - do you pass the string in with the spaces at the end? Because you said "no matter `abc` or `abc def` and not `abc       `. Again my code assumes the string passed to it already has correct final length, because the is what you said.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2 d array of characters

```
char arr[word_count][line_width];
```

You want an array of char * (character pointers).

```
char *arr[word_count];
```

The way you allocate memory won't work too.

Something like this

```
for(int index=0;index<work_count;index++)
  arr[index] = malloc(line_width*sizeof(char)];
```

Don't forget to free at the end of your program or you will have a memory leak.